# How can I get the specific values I selected from SQLite Database? When I click on the button the app jut crashes

Tags: android, sqlite

The button properties.

The java function for button btnLogin

```
    public void LoginT(View v){     
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from Users where username=? and password=?", new String[] {username,password});
         username = c.getString(0);
         password = c.getString(1);

        Toast.makeText(this, (String)username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

I'll use this for a login but I'm just testing displaying the value but nothing happens

Here is the logcat

```
 03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     ... 11 more
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at com.example.twistedfatetraining.Login.LoginT(Login.java:29)
03-11 06:15:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: please post the logcat output... and more releavnt part of Your post. For example, where do You use the button, initialize it etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null

problem is with the selections args in your query. Password is probably null

try checking the input values before running the query:

```
if (username == null || password == null) {
   // show dialog or toast
   return 
}
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from Users where username=? and password=?", new String[] {username, password});
```

Comment: I tried this. It worked. I know the error now :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thy with this code:

```
public void LoginT(View v){     
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from Users where username=? and password=?", new String[] {username,password});
     c.moveToFirst();
     username = c.getString(0);
     password = c.getString(1);

    Toast.makeText(this, (String)username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: Please add comment also.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that You are passing null values to Your query:

```
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from Users where username=? and password=?", new String[] {username,password});
```

You are passing username and password, but they seem to be not initialized at this time. I think You are try to do something other. This has something to be like this:

```
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from Users where username=? and password=?", new String[] {"David","hello"});
```

to get Your query work, username and password must be initializes and valid...